# UNIX - delete specific lines

Tags: shell, unix

I have a list of lines in variable (1,3,8,9). That list shows which lines I need to delete from a text file. which function I can use to delete specific lines number?

Thank you so much for your respond

Comment: This is missing a question.

Comment: `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, `python`, `lua`, `bash`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# set -vx
lines2del="(1,3,8,9)"
sedCmds=${lines2del//,/d;}
sedCmds=${sedCmds/(/}
sedCmds=${sedCmds/)/}
sedCmds=${sedCmds}d
sed -i "$sedCmds" file
```

Remove the # before `set -vx` to see the debug/trace for each cmd as it is executed.

If you don't really have `( )` (parens) around your data, fix the `line2del` variable and remove the second and third `sedCmds=` lines.

IHTH